# Chrome addon to replace string on Facebook not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome

I'm using the following javascript inside the Chrome extension [Web Override](http://weboverride.com/) to attempt to replace certain text on all Facebook pages, but it is not working.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Friend Name', 'Silly Nickname');
}, false);

setTimeout(function(){
 document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Friend Name', 'Silly Nickname');
}, 3000);
```

If I manually run the `replace` function in the console after page load it does what I expect.  Why isn't it running automatically?
The only console error I'm getting is as follows, but I don't think it's related to this plugin/code because it shouldn't be loading jquery.

> Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Unfortunately I can't be sure because the source is `VM1771:7`.

If it *is* the JQuery thing, is there anything I can do?  If not, what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) expects either a string or a regex as the first argument, and in case of a string, it only replaces the first occurrence. That occurrence could be in some metadata, class name, etc.

If you want all occurrences to be replaced, you should use the regex option:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Friend Name/g, 'Silly Nickname');
```

The `g` flag here means "global", i.e apply this to all occurrences. You could also use `gi` for case insensitivity.

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You might want to look into whether or not it's a good idea to replace innerHTML like this (scripts not getting run again, event listeners being lost, etc). Maybe this is not a problem, but it seems like there might be some problems there

Comment: Yeah, it definitely breaks some stuff.  But it's just a gag, so I'm not worried about it.  Thanks again.